# "Люб- (Воздуха! Воздуха!) -лю!" — как называется языковой приём?

Tags: untagged

Читал в специальной литературе о языковом приёме разрыва внутри слова. Чаще он встречается в английском языке (при написании или произношении, например, "blah-blah" (бла-бла) посередине сложного слова для его высмеивания). Закрепил тогда для себя, что в русском языке такой пример есть (отрывок из поэмы Роберта Рождественского), но напрочь забыл, как это называется.